# IOPub Error on Google Colaboratory in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I understand that the below command

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10
```

would let me set the data rate. But on Colab, I cannot run this command since the notebook is already open.

Is there any way I can avoid getting the IOPub error in an active notebook on Colab?

I am running keras code and I get this error when I train my neural network. I really need to see the output since it lets me know how many epochs have been completed and the accuracy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IoPub Error is occurring in Colab because you are trying to display the output on the console itself(Eg. print() statements) which is very large.

So the work around would be, Write the output to the file(instead of print statements) and download the file from the Colab

Note: Please do avoid writing simple print statements(just to print your contents in datasets) when you are training with large dataset

Comment: i have same problem but im not print anything at all just i assigned my result query to a dataframe of pandas

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pprint module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) from python library. It works well from colab. However, colab prints output in limited number of line such as 5,000 lines on screen if it exceeds output limit.

```py
from pprint import pprint

printable = 'long statement'
pprint(printable)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, an "`IOPub data rate exceeded`" occurred in case of internal upload & save in Colab. (Internal transfer is of course fast.) However, when I checked the created file, the file was saved normally.

So I applied the method of ignoring with try exception.

```py
  try:
      w_file_input.save(fn_temp)  # to g-drive.
  except Exception as e :
      print(" ignore : ", e)
```

I hope this helps.