# In Google collab I get IOPub data rate exceeded

Tags: google-colaboratory

IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:

```
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 21):

An IOPub error usually occurs when you try to print a large amount of data to the console. Check your print statements - if you're trying to print a file that exceeds 10MB, its likely that this caused the error. Try to read smaller portions of the file/data.

I faced this issue while reading a file from Google Drive to Colab.
I used this link https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb
and the problem was in this block of code

```py
    # Download the file we just uploaded.
    #
    # Replace the assignment below with your file ID
    # to download a different file.
    #
    # A file ID looks like: 1uBtlaggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz
    file_id = 'target_file_id'
    
    import io
    from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
    
    request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    downloaded = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
      # _ is a placeholder for a progress object that we ignore.
      # (Our file is small, so we skip reporting progress.)
      _, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    
    downloaded.seek(0)

    #Remove this print statement
    #print('Downloaded file contents are: {}'.format(downloaded.read()))
```

I had to remove the last print statement since it exceeded the 10MB limit in the notebook - `print('Downloaded file contents are: {}'.format(downloaded.read()))`
Your file will still be downloaded and you can read it in smaller chunks or read a portion of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct, I just commented the print statement and the error went away. just keeping it here so someone might find it useful. Suppose u are reading a csv file from google drive just import pandas and add pd.read_csv(downloaded) it will work just fine.

```
file_id = 'FILEID'

import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
downloaded = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
done = False
while done is False:
  # _ is a placeholder for a progress object that we ignore.
  # (Our file is small, so we skip reporting progress.)
  _, done = downloader.next_chunk()

downloaded.seek(0)
pd.read_csv(downloaded);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help..

from via sv1997

[IOPub Error on Google Colaboratory in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48906481/iopub-error-on-google-colaboratory-in-jupyter-notebook)

```
IoPub Error is occurring in Colab because you are trying to display the output on the console itself(Eg. print() statements) which is very large.
```

The IoPub Error maybe related in print function.

So delete or annotate the print function. It may resolve the error.

Answer (score -2):

```
%cd darknet
!sed -i 's/OPENCV=0/OPENCV=1/' Makefile
!sed -i 's/GPU=0/GPU=1/' Makefile
!sed -i 's/CUDNN=0/CUDNN=1/' Makefile
!sed -i 's/CUDNN_HALF=0/CUDNN_HALF=1/' Makefile
!apt update
!apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

its important to update your make file. and also, keep your input file name correct